# Передача данных одного класса в другой

Tags: java

Есть класс с set и get методы, есть 2й класс который записывает данные через set (например setTitle("title");), есть еще 3й класс который должен заполучить эти введенные данные, как вызвать 2й класс чтобы данные не были null (сохранялись).

первый класс:

```
   public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
```

второй класс:

```
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("введите название операции");

            First_class f_Class =  new First_class();

            f_Class.setTitle(input.nextLine());
```

3й класс: *как правильно вызвать 3й класс чтобы значение getTitle не было null*

Comment: Добавьте ваш код, чтобы можно было понятнее, с чем придется иметь дело, для правки вопроса нажмите кнопку "править" под текстом вопроса.

Comment: сделано  @SergeyGlazirin

Comment: покажите пож. третий класс и как в нём вы хотите получить данные?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            First_class f_Class =  new First_class();
            Second_class s_Class= new Second_class();
            s_Class.XXX(f_Class);
```